# Copy Paste Command in Text Based Linux Server (No GUI)

Tags: linux

As mentioned in the title, how can I copy and paste text to Linux command line in a **text based Linux server**?

Normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: Start a tmux session (it is most probably already installed). That allows copy-pasting in the pure text mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: This question is about a terminal, not a terminal emulator. A terminal is what you see when you connect a computer without a graphical desktop to a monitor and keyboard (no mouse supported at that point)*

On a text based terminal (not a terminal emulator(!)) copy/paste is *not* possible.

If possible, I recommend to use `ssh` and connect with a  terminal *emulator* which does support copy/paste to that box. For example gnome-terminal could be used for that: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/txt-copy-paste.html

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/paste-command-in-linux/ or xclip are good options

Comment: @RyanSmith Unfortunately older comments have been removed, but we have been talking about a true terminal, not a terminal emulator. This is what you see when you haven't installed a Graphical interface and have a monitor plus keyboard connected to your pc.

Comment: ps: `No GUI` is mentioned in the title of the question

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [xclip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip).

For example, this is how you copy/paste to and from your clipboard:

```
xclip file.txt -selection clipboard; #copy
xclip -selection clipboard -o;       #paste
```

Although normally avialble on OSX, I noticed that my Ubuntu build also has [pbcopy / pbpaste](http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/05/manipulating-the-clipboard-from-the-command-line/).
It should come to no surprise though, that they are just aliases:

```
$ which pbcopy
pbcopy: aliased to xclip -selection clipboard
$ which pbpaste
pbpaste: aliased to xclip -selection clipboard -o
```

Comment: hi, is there any other methods available? xclip is not available in the environment

Comment: Can you install new software?  Use your package manger.  What distro are you on?

Comment: Installing X? :D LOL

Comment: If they're using a text-based OS, xclip is not available, as it relies on the X window system, and if X was running, it wouldn't be a text-based OS.

Answer (score 0):

Retro computers have different sets of combination like.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd> for copying or yanking.

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd> for pasting.

Comment: What do you mean with *retro-computers*? How will you select a line?

Comment: The `readline` command for `yank` and `paste` work some of the time (as would be used in emacs). I still find myself using `ctrl+insert` and `shift+insert` in a number of situations.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't see the use case. (While I want to see it) Can you explain?

Comment: Alright, just yesterday I set up a raspberrypi 3 with rasbian. On boot, I generated ecdsa keys so I could finish the setup from my laptop. On login to the pi (from arch), I find the initial default locale, kbd layout, etc.. is `en_GB`. My keyboard is backwards and normal xterm select buffer copy/paste doesn't work. To handle the issue until I could generate a new locale, I was stuck filling the select buffer on my box and using `shift+ins` to paste into `vim` on the pi. That's one in the last 24 hours.

Comment: What do you mean with `On login to the pi`. Console login (a keyboard and screen attached) or ssh? The OP means the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt install gpm
```

Then use your mouse.